# retrieve latitude and longitude in google map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I can setup a pushpin on map but i am not able to retrieve the latitude and longitude of that point. Here is my code. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

```
 function codeaddress() {
    var geocoder;
    //map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {


            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                flat: false,
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location

            });

            var latt = document.getElementById("latitude");
            latt.value = results[0].geometry.location.getlatitude();
            alert(latt.value);

        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: This needs basic debugging first. What exactly goes wrong where?

Comment: Have you tried results[0].geometry.location.lat()

Comment: Rafe, tried results[0].geometry.location.lat(). Did not get latitude.

Comment: Chrome was not showing the updated pages. Any code changes that i made in javascript were not reflecting when i run the application. The part of the code where i was trying to retrieve the latitude and longitude was added at a later point. These changes were not reflecting. When i deleted browsing history on chrome, i was able to see the changes.

Answer (score 1):

try using `.lat()` instead of `.getLatitude()`.

see the API about the LatLng class: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng

Comment: klassman, i tried .lat() too with same result.